# How to correct this python dfs search?

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am writing python code implementing dfs but i cant get it work correctly. Here is a stupid example using dfs to see if `word` could be formed by `lst`:

```
def dfs(word, gen):
    print(gen)
    if len(gen) <= len(word):
        if gen == word:
            return True
        lst = ["a","b"]
        for i in lst:
            dfs(word, gen+i)
    return False

print(dfs("ba",""))
```

Here my `lst` is ["a", "b"] and it could obviously form "ba". However it returns False. I get the output of the word it formed each time by the `print(gen)`:

```
a
aa
aaa
aab
ab
aba
abb
b
ba
bb
bba
bbb
```

and I could see `ba` in the result, so shouldn't the program stop recursion and returns True once it meets `ba`? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You never check the values returned by the recursive calls to `dfs`.

Comment: You probably just want something like `if dfs(word, gen+i): return True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for i in lst:
    dfs(word, gen+i)
```

Once the word is found it will return `True`, but the caller will ignore the `True` value returned and you will end up generating all the words and returning `False` in any case.
You just need to add a check in order to return `True` when you find the match.

```
for i in lst:
    if dfs(word, gen+i):
        return True
```

Also, moving some line, your function can be written in a more concise way as:

```
def dfs(word, gen):
    if len(gen) > len(word):
        return False
    elif gen == word:
        return True
    else:
        return any(dfs(word, gen+i) for i in ("a","b","c"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the output of `dfs` function ( `if dfs(word, gen+i):` ), i.e.:

```
def dfs(word, gen):
    print(gen)
    if len(gen) <= len(word):
        if gen == word:
            return True
        lst = ["a","b"]
        for i in lst:
            if dfs(word, gen+i):
                return True
    return False

print(dfs("ba",""))
```

---

```
a
aa
aaa
aab
ab
aba
abb
b
ba
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The program doesn't "stop recursion" unless you `return` from every function on the stack.<sup>1</sup>

And you're not doing that. No matter what the recursive call to `dfs` returns, you just ignore it and continue on with your loop:

```
for i in lst:
    dfs(word, gen+i)
```

… and then fall off the end of the loop and the `if` statement and:

```
return False
```

So, those recursive calls have no effect except to waste CPU time. The only way you can ever return anything but `False` at any level is `if gen == word:` at that level. So, when that isn't true at the top level, you always return `False`.

---

The fix is simple: When one of the recursive calls returns `True`, you want to return `True` as well: the value is found if it matches `gen`, or if it's found in a depth-first search on `gen+'a'`, or if it's found in a depth-first search on `gen+'b'`. So:

```
for i in lst:
    if dfs(word, gen+i):
        return True
```

Now you only continue the loop and fall off the end if none of the rercusive calls is true.

---

<sub>1. Unless you raise an unhandled exception.</sub>